# How to start same audio again on stop

Tags: android, audio, service, media-player

In my app I am creating `service` to play audio. When user press any `button` audio stop. But If user not press any `button` and audio file is of length 15 second after 15 second its stop. What I want is after 15 seconds its start again and its stop only when user click `button`.

PlayAudio-

```
public class PlayAudio extends Service{
private static final String LOGCAT = null;
MediaPlayer objPlayer;

public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
objPlayer.start();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
}
return 1;
}

public void onStop(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}

public void onPause(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
public void onDestroy(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent objIndent) {
return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Call that before you start it.

Comment: where I have to add it? I am starting audio from my splashscreen Activity.

Comment: Call it after you call prepare() on your media object

Comment: I am adding it before objPlayer.start(); in above code. Is it correct?

Comment: @JohnR Yeah try it out, see if it works. As a sidenote, you should be calling prepare() on any mediaplayer object before you start it

Comment: sometime sound not play and show error **01-26 04:38:39.870: E/MediaPlayer(1791): Should have subtitle controller already set**

Comment: @JohnR You should post a new question, I dont know what that error is